# How to get file_contents from each url of an urls array

Tags: php, arrays, url, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I am trying to figure out how I can return the file_contents of each url in an array(urls_array). So far the following code , using simplehtmpdom gives me just one result then the code fails to run on.....in the foreach loop.

```
$urlsall = 'http://php.net,
http://php.net/downloads,
http://php.net/docs.php,
http://php.net/get-involved,
http://php.net/support,
http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/introduction.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php,
http://php.net/manual/en/context.php';

$urls_array = explode(',', $urlsall);
//var_dump ($urls_array);
foreach ($urls_array as $url)
    {

         $html = SimpleHtmlDom::file_get_html($url); 
         $title = $html->find('title',0);
        echo $title->plaintext; 

    }
```

results : PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor

```
ERROR: An error occured, The error has been reported.
Error on Dec 18, 2015 17:16PM - file_get_contents( http://php.net/downloads): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in E:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\SimpleHtmlDom.php on line 81
```

What I want to do is get all **the urls titles** from the above foreach loop.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by the urls titles? Could you plz give an example?

Comment: why are you scraping the php manual?

Comment: And why are you creating a string with the urls, instead of declaring the array up front? Exploding on comma will not trim the strings most of the URL's will start with a new line now. That explains why you're getting an error on the second url

Comment: @Sina ... This url: 'http://php.net when you get the $title = $html->find('title',0), it will give you page title : PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor

Comment: He means the titles of html pages linked by those urls.

Comment: You don't want to use SIMPLEHTMLDDOM for a project like this, it's got too many performance issues. Look into something more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in my comment: By the looks of things, the most likely cause of the problem is your using `explode` on a string, using comma's as delimiters. However, your string contains a lot of whitespace, too, which you're not trimming. That would explain why the first URL passes without fault, but the second one fails (that url starts with a new-line character).

I'd suggest you either define an *array* of url's instead of a string you explode, or you trim all the urls:

```
$urls = array_map('trim', explode(',', $urlsall));
```

This calls `trim` for each value in the array that `explode` returns. However, that's a bit silly. You're hard-coding the urls to begin with, so why not write an array instead of a long string?

```
$urls = array(
    'http://php.net',
    'http://php.net/downloads',
    'http://php.net/docs.php',
    'http://php.net/get-involved',
    'http://php.net/support',
    'http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php',
    //rest of the urls here
);
```

Comment: it works after the trimming. Thanks. It's very slow though...Any suggestions to a faster way of doing this?

Comment: @OjObasi: Instead of relying on this `SimpleHtmlDom` class (Don't know where that's coming from), you could see if using `file_get_contents` + `DOMDocument` works. It could speed things up a bit, but I suspect the main source of the overhead is the network latency: you're essentially downloading all of those pages, think of how long each page takes to navigate to in your browser. 1 page doesn't take long, but even if that takes half a second, multiplied by the number of pages, that amounts to several seconds easily

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you have in you array some line break in your array. 
When you do a var_dump of your array I get :

```
array (size=27)
   0 => string 'http://php.net' (length=14)
   1 => string '
      http://php.net/downloads' (length=26)
   2 => string '
       http://php.net/docs.php' (length=25)
   3 => string '
       http://php.net/get-involved' (length=29)
```

Why did you used an explode ? 
Make directly an array to do this :

```
$urlsall = array(
'http://php.net',
'http://php.net/downloads',
'http://php.net/docs.php',
'http://php.net/get-involved',
'http://php.net/support',
'http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/introduction.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.interfaces.php',
'http://php.net/manual/en/context.php'
```

);